# how to call one procedure value to another in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Sp1
{
select count(*) from eventlist
}

sp2(in a int , b out int )
{

set b=call sp1();

}
```

I have to call SP1 value to another SP2 and what ever value will come from SP1 that we have to set Sp1 as Output parameter please tell me how to achieve this I need help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OUTPUT` parameter as you have already mentioned like

```
create procedure sp2 (in a int , out b int )
as
begin
declare @out_value int;
CALL sp1(4, @out_value);
select @out_value;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

CREATE PROCEDURE sp2(in a INT,out b int)
BEGIN
CALL sp1(@value);
SELECT @value; 
END;
```